# Sorting different balls into different slots - check my proof

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

> We have 8 different balls and 4 different slots. In how many ways can you sort the balls into the slots if every slot must at least contain one ball?

I know that one can solve this with the inclusion-exclusion principle but I was wondering why the following approach is wrong?

Firstly there are $\frac{8!}{4!}$ possibilities to sort at least one ball into each slot. Then, there are $4$ balls left which can be arbitrarily sorted into the slots. Hence, we got $\frac{8!}{4!} 4^4$ possibilities in total.

If you consider that there are only $4^8$ ways if you do not impose any restriction  one can see that my idea must be wrong.

But where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcounting.  If you put balls AB in slot 1, CD in slot 2, EF in slot 3, and GH in slot 4, you will count this sixteen times, once for each combination of balls that make up the first four.

Comment: Is there any possibility to calculate all ways following my approach? So, if you take $\frac{8!}{4!}$ as a starting point and then add all possibilities to sort the remaining 4 balls into the 4 slots?

Comment: You would have to condition on the final distribution of the balls.  If there are two in each bin you divide by $16$, if there are five in one bin and one in each other you divide by $5$ and so on.